# Using .net web app function in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to add this function into`WCF` (which new to me) so that I can call this function as a service later. But I receive this error:

> The name 'imgprofile' does not exist in the current context.

Anyone know please share their ideas or solutions.

[image: Error Line]